# May a non-Jew participate in parts of a Jewish burial?

Tags: gentiles, funeral-burial-levaya

May a non-Jew participate in any of these parts of a Jewish burial (assume there is no separate "funeral" in a home and everything is graveside?

- *Hesped* - giving the main "speech"
- carrying the coffin
- assisting with lowering the coffin into the grave
- shoveling dirt onto the grave
- reciting Kaddish if he can read Hebrew but none of the mourners can. (Obviously, he is not part of the minyan.)

Comment: Why do you suppose a non-Jew may not do any of these things?

Answer (score 2):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus 51:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=266) mentions that it is forbidden to hear a Hesped from a priest or someone similar to a priest. In the notes he says it is forbidden as they speak about their religion and wear a cross. This would lead me to believe that a regular non Jew may deliver a eulogy.

[5:15](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=67) he mentions in the name of the Avodas Hagershuni that a non Jew should not be involved with the burial and [even the driver of the vehicle](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=68) should be a Jew.

[Divros Eliyahu 4:2 - page 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48334&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=) concludes that one may answer Amein on a non Jews Bracha - so long you heard the entire Bracha. Thus I do not see an issue with the Kaddish.

Comment: @mevaqesh:  "This would lead me to believe that a regular non Jew may deliver a eulogy."

Comment: Yeah but I was a bit bothered by quoting a low level recent writer as a halacha pesuka that it is forbidden to hear a Hesped from a priest or someone similar to a priest. Furthermore, I take issue with saying that a non-Jew should not be involved with the burial, which even the NG can find no major halachic sources for. I seems like an example of making up new halachos.

Comment: @mevaqesh: He brings it from the [Avodas Hagershuni](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/19570) published over 300 years ago.

Comment: Exactly. We have a small hitter who dug up a somehat obscure acharon to make a new chumra, not found in Mishna, Tosefta, Mechilta, Sifri Sifra, Bavli, Yerushalmi, Geonim, Rambam, Rishonim, Tur, Shulchan Aruch, Chaye Adam, Kitzur, MB, Aruch Hashulchan, or major responsa: Rabbi Akiva Eiger, Chassam Sofer, Yabia Omer, etc.

Comment: RE: Divrei Eliyahu saying we can answer Amen to a non-Jew's Bracha - I'm not sure that means we also make him say the Kaddish, just that we can respond Amen to a blessing that was said.

Comment: The question is "may he participate" mot whether WE can MAKE him say Kaddish.